# decrease the widgets size when open keyboard with flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quick_answers/view/constants.dart';
import 'package:quick_answers/view/widgets/category_card_widget.dart';
import 'package:quick_answers/view/widgets/search_widget.dart';

import '../widgets/categories_widget.dart';
import '../widgets/home_details_widget.dart';

class MobileLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MobileLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
                child: SearchWidget()
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
                child: ListWidgetView(direction: Axis.horizontal,)
            ),

          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: HomeDetailsWidget(),
          )
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

[image]

so, i don't want to decrease the size of widgets when keyboard open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Scaffold`, set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false`

Like so:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: ...
);
```